# Can you use PHP inside of pug files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pug

I'm new to PUG (previously Jade) and I think its an amazingly clean way of generating html fast and reducing quite a errors I may make when I forget to close my divs.

The thing is, I create custom wordpress themes so I currently code my php and html in php files. For example:-

```
<div style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('example');?>');"></div>
```

But the way PUG works is based on indentation. So my pug file would look like:-

```
div(style="background-image:url('');")
```

But where I would normally put my php tag (in between the background image url brackets, I can't pug renders the `<` as  `&lt;` so what can I do or what do I do?

Is there a way to include php tags inside of pug or is it php and html for the win?

So is there no way I can use my php tags inside of my PUG files?

Cheers!

Comment: https://github.com/pug-php/pug It has a PHP fork

Comment: Ive looked at this but im very new to all of this and not to great with understanding these pages haha. I need somebody to explain it to me like a 5 year old

Comment: I think you're at the wrong spot then, That's not really the idea behind SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. It's a templating engine. PHP is a completely different animal and isn't just included inline as such.

If you want to include PHP, you'd have to find a way of calling a PHP script separately and then including the result in your template.

Or you could somehow have PHP build the template code, then pass that to PUG, but now you're getting weird.

Comment: It's not a javascript templating engine, it's an HTML templating engine.

Comment: `Pug is a high performance template engine heavily influenced by Haml and implemented with JavaScript for Node.js and browsers.` https://github.com/pugjs/pug

Comment: The fact it's *implemented* with javascript doesn't make it a *javascript templating engine*

Comment: **Pug is a clean, whitespace sensitive syntax for writing html.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that Pug doesn't escape the contents of the attribute (within the `""`).

Instead of

```
div(style="background-image:url('<?php the_field(); ?>');")
```

You would add an `!` and write

```
div(style!="background-image:url('<?php the_field(); ?>');")
```

---

Reference: https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#unescaped-attributes